# Count customers Lost vs Active through CASE expression

Tags: sql, case

I am trying to create flag with customers lost/active. I have 4 quarters and if they did not buy in last two quarters (0, 1) I consider them lost. But I want to apply the flag for the whole ID despite they had revenue in remaining two quarters (2,3). Now is showing me lost for 0, 1 but active for 2, 3 in case there was revenue.

I know my case when condition is wrong and is showing results based on I written there but do not know how to figure it out.

What I have tried:

```
CASE WHEN ISNULL(Q_0_Flag, 0) = 1 AND ISNULL(Q_1_Flag, 0) = 1 THEN 'Active' 
     WHEN ISNULL(Q_0_Flag, 0) = 0 AND ISNULL(Q_1_Flag, 0) = 1 THEN 'Active' 
     WHEN ISNULL(Q_0_Flag, 0) = 1 AND ISNULL(Q_1_Flag, 0) = 0 THEN 'Active' 
     ELSE 'Lost' 
END AS 'PR Flag'
```

Full Code

```
  SELECT DISTINCT 
            [crm bp id], 
            revenue, 
            qtr, 
            qtr_flag, 
            Q_0_Flag, 
            Q_1_Flag, 
          CASE
                WHEN ISNULL(Q_0_Flag, 0) = 1
                     AND ISNULL(Q_1_Flag, 0) = 1
                THEN 'Active'
                WHEN ISNULL(Q_0_Flag, 0) = 0
                     AND ISNULL(Q_1_Flag, 0) = 1
                THEN 'Active'
                WHEN ISNULL(Q_0_Flag, 0) = 1
                     AND ISNULL(Q_1_Flag, 0) = 0
                THEN 'Active'
                ELSE 'Lost'
            END AS 'PR Flag'
     FROM
     (
         SELECT a.[crm bp id], 
                ISNULL(h.rev, 0) AS revenue, 
                a.qtr, 
                h.qtr_flag,
                CASE
                    WHEN a.qtr IN('Q120')
                         AND ISNULL(h.rev, 0) <> 0
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END AS 'Q_0_Flag',
                CASE
                    WHEN a.qtr IN('Q419')
                         AND ISNULL(h.rev, 0) <> 0
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END AS 'Q_1_Flag'
         FROM Accounts AS A
              LEFT JOIN
         (
             SELECT crm_bp_id, 
                    ISNULL(SUM(net_revenue), 0) AS rev, 
                    [Cal].[Qtr_Flag], 
                    cal.lqyy
             FROM Historical Revenue AS h
                  LEFT JOIN Calendar AS cal ON cal.cdate = h.inv_date
             WHERE cal.qtr_flag IN('1', '2', '3')
                  AND [Business_Group] <> 'DCG'
             GROUP BY h.crm_bp_id, 
                      cal.qtr_flag, 
                      cal.lqyy
             UNION ALL
             SELECT a.crm_bp_id, 
                   ISNULL(SUM(net_revenue), 0) AS rev, 
                   [Cal].[Qtr_Flag], 
                   cal.lqyy
            FROM Actual Revenue AS a
                 LEFT JOIN Calendar AS cal ON cal.cdate = a.inv_date
            GROUP BY crm_bp_id, 
                     [Cal].[Qtr_Flag], 
                     cal.lqyy
        ) AS h ON h.crm_bp_id = A.[crm bp id]
                  AND h.lqyy = a.qtr
    ) AS T
```

What I get

```
ID QTR Rev Flag
1  0    0   Lost
1  3  1000  Active
2  1  2000  Active
2  1  2000  Active
2  1  2000  Active
```

What I Want

```
ID QTR Rev Flag
1  0    0   Lost
1  3  1000  Lost
2  1  2000  Active
2  1  2000  Active
2  1  2000  Active
```

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit your question instead!

Comment: Hi! Thanks, I do not know why it did not let me post with my code :( is just part of it I wanted to show you full

Comment: Show us some sample table data and also the expected result. (Formatted text please. No images.)

Comment: I am sorry I do not know how to format in here...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Can you see properly now? Thank you for your help

Comment: When formatting, use `{}` for code and sample data (will be grey), and use `"` for error messages (will be yellow). Don't combine.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: It is T-SQL Microsoft, I wrote it there but administrator adjusted the subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment that you don't need to see the Quarterly data, your final statement could be along the lines of:

```
SELECT
     [crm bp id], 
     LastYearRevenue = sum(revenue), 
     PR_Flag = 
          CASE (SUM(Q_0_Flag) > 0) OR (SUM(Q_1_Flag) > 0) 
               THEN 'Active' 
               ELSE 'Lost'
          END
From QuarterlyRevenue
Group by [crm bp id]
```

The entirety of your query could certainly be simplified, but there isn't anything logically wrong with the rest. Putting everything together you have:

```
With QuarterlyRevenue as
     (
         SELECT a.[crm bp id], 
                ISNULL(h.rev, 0) AS revenue, 
                a.qtr, 
                h.qtr_flag,
                CASE
                    WHEN a.qtr IN('Q120')
                         AND ISNULL(h.rev, 0) <> 0
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END AS 'Q_0_Flag',
                CASE
                    WHEN a.qtr IN('Q419')
                         AND ISNULL(h.rev, 0) <> 0
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END AS 'Q_1_Flag'
         FROM Accounts AS A
              LEFT JOIN
         (
             SELECT crm_bp_id, 
                    ISNULL(SUM(net_revenue), 0) AS rev, 
                    [Cal].[Qtr_Flag], 
                    cal.lqyy
             FROM Historical Revenue AS h
                  LEFT JOIN Calendar AS cal ON cal.cdate = h.inv_date
             WHERE cal.qtr_flag IN('1', '2', '3')
                  AND [Business_Group] <> 'DCG'
             GROUP BY h.crm_bp_id, 
                      cal.qtr_flag, 
                      cal.lqyy
             UNION ALL
             SELECT a.crm_bp_id, 
                   ISNULL(SUM(net_revenue), 0) AS rev, 
                   [Cal].[Qtr_Flag], 
                   cal.lqyy
            FROM Actual Revenue AS a
                 LEFT JOIN Calendar AS cal ON cal.cdate = a.inv_date
            GROUP BY crm_bp_id, 
                     [Cal].[Qtr_Flag], 
                     cal.lqyy
        ) AS h ON h.crm_bp_id = A.[crm bp id]
                  AND h.lqyy = a.qtr
    )
SELECT
            [crm bp id], 
            LastYearRevenue = sum(revenue), 
        PR_Flag = CASE (SUM(Q_0_Flag) > 0) OR (SUM(Q_1_Flag) > 0) THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Lost' END
From QuarterlyRevenue
Group by [crm bp id]
```

Comment: What I need is, if the customer had zero revenue in 0 & 1 (which is actual and last quarter) but had revenue in quarters 2, 3 I still want to it appear as lost for every ID, because it doesnt matter if they bought 3 quarters back, they are no longer considered as active. Now looking at the example I made a mistake apologies.

Comment: Can you please update your examples to correctly show what you need vs your current results?

Comment: Example adjusted, the row you pointed out should have the QTR 3, hope now makes sense

Comment: Do you actually care about seeing each Quarter as a separate line, or do you just want to know if they are Active or Lost?

Comment: Active/Lost per ID is enough

Comment: Is working thank you so much :) If the query can be simplified and you had time to share your view, I would be also interested to see the other solution. And one more question, If I wanted to make it dynamic, whenever I select a quarter this will be working from that quarter to the past. Example, now we are in actual quarter, looking back 3 quarters, then I will be in previous quarter and again looking back 3 quarters from that date is it too complicated from this solution?

Comment: I think you could make that work by modifying your join to the calendar and revenue tables, and updating your flag calculations.